# CPAN - yaml_process_error when i try install for module 'IO::EventMux'

Tags: perl, cpan

Hi i've been trying to search for a fix to this but i cant find one. I need install for module 'IO::EventMux', so i use:

```
cpan[1]> install IO::EventMux
```

However i get the following error:

```
Catching error: "CPAN::Exception::yaml_process_error=HASH(0xe34ed78)" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/CPAN.pm line 392
    CPAN::shell() called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/App/Cpan.pm line 339
    App::Cpan::_process_options('App::Cpan') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/App/Cpan.pm line 422
    App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan') called at /usr/local/bin/cpan line 12
```

I'm using perl version 5.14.2 on Linux 3.11.0-15-generic x86_64.

My yaml_module is set to 'YAML'.

```
cpan[3]> o conf yaml_module
    yaml_module        [YAML]
```

I tried switching to YAML::XS and YAML::Sync too, but i got the following report:

```
cpan[4]> reports TLBDK/IO-EventMux-2.02.tar.gz
Distribution: T/TL/TLBDK/IO-EventMux-2.02.tar.gz
Fetching 'http://www.cpantesters.org/show/IO-EventMux.yaml'...DONE

2.02:
 -FAIL 5.18.1 on GNU/Linux 3.2.0-4-486 (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.16.3 on GNU/Linux 3.8.0-32-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.16.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-348.16.1.el5 (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.18.0 on GNU/Linux 3.8.0-23-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.16.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-686 (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 3.2.0-3-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.16.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-686 (i686-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.14.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-686 (i686-linux-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.14.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-686 (i686-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.17.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.25-14.fc9.i686 (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.17.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.22.14-72.fc6 (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int-ld)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.16.0 on GNU/Linux 3.4.0-1-arch (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.17.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-ld)
 +PASS 5.17.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.17.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.15.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.16.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-ld)
 -FAIL 5.17.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-ld)
 +PASS 5.17.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.16.0 RC0 on FreeBSD 8.0-release-p4 (i386-freebsd)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (i686-linux)
 -FAIL 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux-multi)
 -FAIL 5.14.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-kirkwood (armv5tel-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.15.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.14.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.7 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.7 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.15.7 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.7 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.14.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.15.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (i686-linux-ld)
 +PASS 5.15.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-ld)
 +PASS 5.15.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.12.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (i686-linux-ld)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-ld)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38.8-35.fc15.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38.8-35.fc15.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.14.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38.8-35.fc15.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-27-server (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int-ld)
 +PASS 5.13.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.13.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (i686-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux-multi)
 -FAIL 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (i686-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.14.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.14.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux-multi)
 -FAIL 5.15.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38.8-35.fc15.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.13.11 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.15.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.13.11 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.14.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.15.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.38-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.14.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-ld)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux-multi)
 -FAIL 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.12.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.1 on Windows (Win32) 5.2 (MSWin32-x86-multi-thread)
 +PASS 5.15.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-ld)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.15.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.14.1 on Windows (Win32) 5.00 (MSWin32-x86-multi-thread)
 -FAIL 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 -FAIL 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-28-server (i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.15.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.4 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.15.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.14.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.15.0 on Windows (Win32) 5.00 (MSWin32-x86-multi-thread)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.4 RC2 on FreeBSD 8.0-release (i386-freebsd)
 +PASS 5.12.4 RC1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.13.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.13.11 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.14.0 on Windows (Win32) 5.00 (MSWin32-x86-multi-thread)
 +PASS 5.12.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.14.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-28-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.14.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.11-83.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-28-server (i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-28-server (i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.13.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.13.11 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-27-server (i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.13.11 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-686 (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.12.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.13.11 on FreeBSD 8.0-release (i386-freebsd)
 +PASS 5.12.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.13.7 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33.4 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.13.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.13.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.3 on GNU/Linux 2.6.36-arch (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.13.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.9-64.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.6-48.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.13.7 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35.6-48.fc14.x86_64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-23-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.13.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-openvz-686 (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.34-0.slh.9-sidux-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33-arch (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.13.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.34-0.slh.9-sidux-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-27-server (i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-openvz-686 (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-27-server (i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-27-server (i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-4.slh.9-aptosid-686 (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.13.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-27-server (i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32.17-dsa-ia32 (i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.35-4.slh.9-aptosid-686 (i686-linux)
 -FAIL 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.34-0.slh.9-sidux-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.13.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.34-0.slh.9-sidux-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.12.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.34-0.slh.9-sidux-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
*+PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.13.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.13.5 on FreeBSD 8.0-release (i386-freebsd)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33-arch (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int-ld)
 +PASS 5.12.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.13.4 on FreeBSD 8.0-release (i386-freebsd)
 -FAIL 5.12.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.1 on FreeBSD 8.0-release (i386-freebsd)
 -FAIL 5.12.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.33-arch (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.12.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-openvz-686 (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.13.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-686 (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.13.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-686 (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.13.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-686 (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-53.el5 (i386-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.12.0 on FreeBSD 8.0-release (i386-freebsd)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.1 on FreeBSD 8.0-release (i386-freebsd)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-686 (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.31-16-generic (i686-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.11.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.31-16-generic (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.11.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.31-14-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 patch 35104 on GNU/Linux 2.6.31-14-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.60-0.31-default (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-128.1.10.el5 (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.60-0.31-default (s390x-linux)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.31-14-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.11.2 on Windows (Win32) 5.2 (MSWin32-x86-multi-thread)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-128.1.10.el5 (s390x-linux)
 +PASS 5.11.2 patch v5.11.2-23-g0b93a79 on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 -FAIL 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.11.2 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-openvz-686 (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.11.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.31-14-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-15-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-24-generic (i686-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.27.19-5-default (s390x-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.27.19-5-default (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.5-7.315-s390 (s390-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.5-7.315-s390 (s390-linux)
 -FAIL 5.11.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-15-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 patch 35104 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-15-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-686 (i686-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-15-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.11.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-15-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 patch 35104 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-15-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.11.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-15-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-15-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-14-generic (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.0 on FreeBSD 7.0-release (amd64-freebsd)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.1 on FreeBSD 7.0-release (amd64-freebsd)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int)
 +PASS 5.11.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-13-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.1 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-13-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.9 on OpenBSD 4.4 (OpenBSD.i386-openbsd)
 +PASS 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-23-server (i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-16-generic (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-16-generic (i686-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-23-server (i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.11.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-13-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 patch 35104 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-13-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-13-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 patch 35104 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-13-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.17.14 (armv5tejl-linux)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-13-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 patch 35104 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 -FAIL 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.27.19-5-default (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.27.19-5-default (s390x-linux)
 -FAIL 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.11.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.8.9 patch 35104 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (x86_64-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-16-generic (i686-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-16-generic (i686-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.27.19-5-default (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-24-generic (i686-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-686 (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.30-020630rc7-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.27.19-5-default (s390x-linux)
 +PASS 5.8.9 patch 35104 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int-ld)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.27.19-5-default (s390x-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-686 (i686-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24.5-xeon-aufs20081006-grsec (x86_64-linux)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-19-server (i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.11.0 patch blead on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.9.5 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.28-11-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-ld)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.27.19-5-default (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-16-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.6.2 on FreeBSD 7.0-release (amd64-freebsd)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.5-7.315-s390 (s390-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-16-generic (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-16-generic (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.0 on FreeBSD 7.0-release (amd64-freebsd-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-16-generic (i686-linux)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.38 (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int-ld)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.38 (i686-linux-thread-multi-64int-ld)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-5-alpha-generic (alpha-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.5-7.315-s390 (s390-linux)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.5-7.315-s390 (s390-linux)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on FreeBSD 7.0-release (amd64-freebsd)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.5-7.315-s390 (s390-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.5-7.315-s390 (s390-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.0 on Mac OS X 8.10.1 (darwin-thread-multi-2level)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-4-xen-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
 +PASS 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-4-xen-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.0 on Mac OS X 9.1.0 (darwin-thread-multi-2level)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.26-1-amd64 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.9 on FreeBSD 7.0-release (amd64-freebsd)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on FreeBSD 7.0-release (amd64-freebsd)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.60-0.31-default (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.60-0.31-default (s390x-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.0 patch 35117 on GNU/Linux 2.6.22-1-k7 (i686-linux-64int)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.22-1-k7 (i686-linux-64int)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.9 patch 35054 on GNU/Linux 2.6.22-1-k7 (i686-linux-64int)
  UNKNOWN 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.22-1-k7 (i686-linux-64int)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.6 on GNU/Linux 2.6.22-1-k7 (i686-linux-64int)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.60-0.31-default (s390x-linux)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.24-1-amd64 (x86_64-linux)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-92.1.18.el5 (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.60-0.31-default (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.8.9 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-92.1.18.el5 (s390x-linux)
 +PASS 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-14-ovz-686 (i686-linux-thread-multi)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-92.1.18.el5 (s390x-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.60-0.31-default (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-92.el5 (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.16.60-0.31-default (s390x-linux)
  UNKNOWN 5.8.8 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-92.1.18.el5 (s390x-linux-thread-multi)
 -FAIL 5.10.0 on GNU/Linux 2.6.18-92.el5 (s390x-linux)
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem, resulting in some test fail. So the module can't install successfully. I install `Date::Calc`, and I solve my problem with `sudo make install UNINST=1` finally. uninstall the module then install it successfully.